# Unable to find any artifacts for the associated workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, codacy

trying to download the codacy coverage report from github. using this below code in workflow

```
name: codacy-coverage-reporter

on: ["push"]

jobs:
  codacy-coverage-reporter:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: codacy-coverage-reporter
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run codacy-coverage-reporter
        uses: codacy/codacy-coverage-reporter-action@v1
        with:
          project-token: XXXXXXXXXXXX
          coverage-reports: coverage/angular-forms-and-validations/lcov.info
    
  download-reporter: 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: codacy-coverage-reporter
    steps:
      - name: Download codacy-coverage-reporter
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: public

      - name: Extract codacy-coverage-reporter
        run: tar xvf codacy-coverage-reporter.tar.gz
```

but not able to download the report from github.[image]
this message showing.

**can anyone please review my code and give a solution for download the report?**

Comment: The upload step is missing in your first job.

Comment: Reference for the [upload-artifact action](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact)